# Monitoring Performance Counters With IIS Express

Tags: performance, iis-express

I am attempting to look at ASP.Net performance counters with a running instance of IIS Express.  This [article](https://robinsedlaczek.com/2014/04/07/measure-performance-of-asp-net-web-applications-with-microsoft-performance-monitor-2/)  hints that it is possible but I do not see any details of how to do get the "Instances of selected object" to show IIS Express instances.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this.  The statement in the referenced article, "Using the performance counters with IIS Express requires to start the Visual Studio for the Asp.Net web application as an administrator." isn't true and threw me off.

When selecting IIS instances in Perfmon I would get this list:
[image]

The difficult thing was that the counters for _LM_W3SVC_1_ROOT were counting for both standard IIS as well as my instance of IIS Express. Obviously, this throws off the performance counters.  I found that the number in the instance list corresponds to the ID of the site.  I renumbered the sites in my applicationhost.config file to start at 100 so that I can separate IIS instances from IIS Express instances.  You don't have to use Visual Studio to start IIS Express and the performance counters do work properly when the site id is separated from IIS's site ids.